# Why does Model.find behaviour in a deployed environment differ from that in a development enviroment?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite3-ruby

Using Ruby on Rails combined with capistrano and git, I've run into an annoying problem..

I have a controller "people" with the index action that looks something like this:

```
def index
  @people = Person.find( :conditions => params[:search] )
end
```

There is a boolean "is_admin" column in the Person table. Assuming that some of the people are admin and some are not, a get call to **http://localhost:3000/people?search[is_admin]=true** should populate **@people** with some users... And this is true for my local pc when I run the app in **development** mode..

But.... When I deploy to my server account ( railsplayground ), a call to **http://mydomain.com/people?search[is_admin]=true** fails to find any matching items. 
However, if I change **...?search[is_admin]=true** to **...?search[is_admin]=1** the response returns the administrator users as expected...

Back on my local pc, the use of "1" instead of "true" fails.

The bottom line is that

```
Person.find( :all, :conditions => { :is_admin => 'true' } )
```

works my development environment, and

```
Person.find( :all, :conditions => { :is_admin => 1 } )
```

works in my deployed environment.

Why is this? and how can I fix it?

Ideally I would like to place links like:

```
link_to( "Administrators", {
  :controller => '/people',
  :action => :index,
  :search => { :is_admin => true }
})
```

and get a lists of administrators :).

*Might be worthy to note that my development database is a sqlite3 file, and production is a mysql database...*

EDIT: I understand the objections to user-input, but in this exceptional case it is a very very minor threat. Also, my current code works perfectly in either my development pc, or my production account, but not on both. The easiest sollution seems to change the way sqlite3 saves and interperets boolean values, so I would change my question to "how do I change the way sqlite saves boolean values"... If sqlite would mimic mysql's behavior perfectly, it would serve my developments needs perfectly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a boolean value as string and the final behavior depends on the active database. Here's a more detailed explanation.

When you read the `params[:search]` variable, the content is a string and there's no type. This is because the query string can't understand whether

```
params[:search][:is_admin] = "true"
```

actually means

```
params[:search][:is_admin] = "true"
params[:search][:is_admin] = true
```

Likewise, when you pass 1 you end up with

```
params[:search][:is_admin] = "1"
```

which is different than

```
params[:search][:is_admin] = 1
```

When you pass the value to the query, because you are not passing a boolean, the value is not translated by the database adapter. Your final query result in something like

```
SELECT * FROM `persons` WHERE `persons.is_admin` = 'true'
```

SQLite3 stores boolean as t/f strings. `true` is stored as `'t'` and `false` is stored as `'f'`. I guess it also understands true/false and it automatically translates your query.
On the opposite, MySQL understands only 0/1 and true/false and it fails.

When you switch the behavior, passing `1` instead of `true`, you are causing SQLite to fail because it can't translate the string `"1"` to `'t'`. On the opposite, MySQL can and it does.

In both case, you are doing it wrong. You shouldn't pass a string but a boolean value. Also, you should never trust user input.

My suggestion is to normalize your `params[:search]` before feeding `Person.find`.

Comment: can sqlite be patched or fixed to mimic mysql 100%? ( read the edit )

Comment: Check out Searchlogic. http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic It does more or less what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think the difference between using sqlite and mysql is the cause of your issue.

But allowing active record conditioned to be passed in directly from the query string seems like a bad idea to me, and could leave your app open to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

@Simone answer explains why you get such a behavior. To get correct result in both sqlite3 and mysql you should pass:

```
Person.find( :all, :conditions => { :is_admin => true } )
```

If you will have only one level of parameters (you have `params[:search][:something]` but nothing deeper) than you can create correct hash with conditions like this:

```
my_conditions = Hash.new
params[:search].each do |item, value|
  my_conditions[item.to_sym] = value == 'true' ? true : value == 'false' ? false : value
end
```

It will iterate over all search params and will change all `'true'` to `true` and `'false'` to `false`. If there will be other value it will leave it as it is. Of course you can put here any logic you want. If it will get more complicated than you can rewrite it with `if` or with `switch`.

Than you can:

```
Person.all(:conditions => my_conditions)
```